# How do you call ubercart's shopping cart block?

Tags: theming, blocks, ubercart

I have a need to manually call and place the UC shopping cart block. I know that to call the block it would be something like this;

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', #);
print render($block);
?>
```

I tried;

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 'cart');
print render($block);
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('uc_cart', 'block_view', 'cart');
print render($block);
?>
```

Neither worked. How do I properly do this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to render the code using the following;

```
<?php 
  $block = block_load('uc_cart', 'cart'); 
  $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
  print $output; 
?>
```